# Is $2p-2$ a period of $\{a_n\}$ modulo a prime $p$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let ${a_0}=1$, ${a_n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n}{2k}a_ka_{n-k-1}$ for $n>0$. That is, ${a_n}=$ [A002067](http://oeis.org/A002067)(n) in OEIS.

Question: for any prime $p$, is $2p-2$ a period of $\{a_n\}$ modulo $p$?

And it looks like $p-1$ is a period of $\{a_n\}$ modulo $p$ when $p\equiv3\mod 4$.

Comment: How much have you confirmed this, numerically?

Comment: It is true for every prime $p<1000$.

Comment: As an aside: The number 4369 is the only term that corresponds to a constructible regular polygon ... and that number is the smallest such number ending in 9.

Comment: Note that [the periods in question](https://oeis.org/A122159) are also in the OEIS.

Comment: Some numerical computations suggest that if p>2 is prime, and d is the minimal period of {a_n} mod p, then d = 2(p-1) iff p = 4k+1, otherwise p-1 = d or 2d iff (p-1)!! == 1 or -1 (mod p).